# Left Shift/Control/Option keys don't work

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, keyboard, repair

Yesterday the shift stopped working most of the time (it works 1/100) suddenly (did not spill anything), and the weird thing is that today the Control & Option keys joined the party — they stopped working (only left keys).

It's a MacBook Pro "Core i7" 2.2 15" Mid-2015 (IG) (MJLQ2LL/A).

I have tried the keys in my Windows VMWare and they don't work. In keyboard viewer in Mac they are not highlighted when tapped.

How to know for sure if this is a hardware issue (with keyboard or elsewhere too) and how can I fix the problem?

Update: External bluetooth works fine

Comment: try an external keyboard.  if it works ok, the internal one probably needs repair

Comment: @TomGewecke if it works what kind of repair I need ? how much it cost ?

Comment: You need to consult a repair shop to get info like that

Comment: @TomGewecke external bluetooth keyboard works fine

Comment: You have to replace the top case assembly.  If not under AppleCare, you're looking at $300-400 USD.

Answer (score 0):

Try resetting the NVRAM on your Mac using this guide - https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204063

If those keys do not work even after the NVRAM reset, then you will have to consult with a repair shop or go to the Apple Store and ask to get your keyboard fixed or replaced.

Comment: Thanks, Allan.  This worked for me.  Very strange symptoms - left shift key didn't work in apps or the Finder.  But the Keyboard Viewer utility showed the correct key press.  AND, while the Keyboard Viewer was open, the left shift key worked correctly in all apps.  Pretty weird, but a simple way to rule out mechanical issues.